# EWS Load Property Before Reading Value Error During Email Sending

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I am trying to attach an original email as an attachment to a new email, which will be sent out.

I met the following error:

> Message      : You must load or assign this property before you can
>   read its value. Inner Exception   :  Stack Trace  :    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.get_Item(PropertyDefinition
>   propertyDefinition)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.get_Sender()    at
>   Service1.Email.SendUpdateEmail(EmailMessage email, String
>   caseNumber, String autoDiscoverUrl) in C:\trunk\SRC\Email.cs:line 160

Below is my code:

```
public static void SendUpdateMail(EmailMessage email, string caseNumber, string autoDiscoverUrl)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try
    {
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(autoDiscoverUrl);
        EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage(service);
        EmailMessage OriginalEmail = email;
        PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
        psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
        OriginalEmail.Load(psPropset);
        ItemAttachment Attachment = mail.Attachments.AddItemAttachment<EmailMessage>();
        Attachment.Item.MimeContent = OriginalEmail.MimeContent;
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_Flags = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        Attachment.Item.SetExtendedProperty(PR_Flags, "1");
        Attachment.Name = OriginalEmail.Subject;
        mail.Subject = "Case Created";
        mail.ToRecipients.Add(OriginalEmail.Sender);
        mail.SendAndSaveCopy();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogFile.AppendError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I would like to seek some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these lines you have loaded a very restricted property set into OriginalEmail

```
    PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
    psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
    OriginalEmail.Load(psPropset);
```

Then you try to access the Sender address (which is the property the error is telling you its having a problem with)

```
       mail.ToRecipients.Add(OriginalEmail.Sender);
```

Because you haven't included the Sender in the PropertySet your getting that error so all you should need to do is add EmailMessageSchema.Sender to it eg

```
    PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
    psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
    psPropset.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Sender);
    OriginalEmail.Load(psPropset);
```